# Does netstat on windows persist logs of old connections?

Tags: windows, logging, netstat

I need to verify if a computer was hacked or if it has suspicious activity. Is a PC running on windows so I am wonder if there is a way to check a log with old connections activities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no logging if you don't separately set it up in advanced.

Your better off monitoring the traffic from the network side as root kits and hide traffic from the usually logging sources.

If you can either connect the computer to another one with 2 NIC or plug both into a dumb hub.  Then you could use that computer to monitor traffic.  NIC 1 your network, and network 2 the infected PC.

Windows you could use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), or tcpdump for linux.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The thing is that I need to check if the computer was compromised in the past. I mean I am looking for footprints that could exists in the computer now. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could use a utility to scan your registry and/or files.  You could try the trial version of malwarebytes.org.    You need to attach the hard drive to another computer, but **do not boot from it**, and use tools on the other computer to scan this hard drive so if there are any root kits or etc they won't be active.